# torch Parameter grad return none

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, quantization

I want to implement learned size quantization algorithm. And I create a quante Linear layer

```py
class QLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, out_dim, bits=8):
        super(QLinear, self).__init__()
        # create a tensor requires_grad=True
        self.up = 2 ** bits - 1
        self.down = 0
        self.fc = nn.Linear(input_dim, out_dim)
        weight = self.fc.weight.data
        self.scale = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor((torch.max(weight) - torch.min(weight)) / (self.up - self.down)), requires_grad=True)
        self.zero_point = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(self.down - (torch.min(weight) / self.scale).round()), requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        weight = self.fc.weight
        quant_weight = (round_ste(weight / self.scale) + self.zero_point)
        quant_weight = torch.clamp(quant_weight, self.down, self.up)
        dequant_weight = ((quant_weight - self.zero_point) * self.scale)
        self.fc.weight.data = dequant_weight
        return self.fc(x)


class QNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = QLinear(28 * 28, 100)
        self.fc2 = QLinear(100, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.softmax(x)
        return x
```

when I train this network,scale's grad always return None. Why this happen and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing `dequant_weight` through data attribute of your parameter which ends up not being registered by autograd. A simple alternative would be to handle `weight` as a [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html) and apply a linear operator manually in the forward definition directly with the computed weight `dequant_weight`.

Here is a minimal example that should work:

```
class QLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, out_dim, bits=8):
        super().__init__()
        self.up = 2 ** bits - 1
        self.down = 0

        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(out_dim, input_dim))
        self.scale = nn.Parameter(
            torch.Tensor((self.weight.max() - self.weight.min()) / (self.up - self.down)))
        self.zero_point = nn.Parameter(
            torch.Tensor(self.down - (self.weight.min() / self.scale).round()))

    def forward(self, x):
        quant_weight = (torch.round(self.weight / self.scale) + self.zero_point)
        quant_weight = torch.clamp(quant_weight, self.down, self.up)
        dequant_weight = ((quant_weight - self.zero_point) * self.scale)
        return F.linear(x, dequant_weight)
```

---

Side notes:

- `nn.Parameter` requires gradient computation by default (no need to provide `requires_grad=True`.
- Additionally you can reformat `QNet` by inheriting from [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html) to avoid boilerplate code:

  ```
  class QNet(nn.Sequential):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__(nn.Flatten(),
                          QLinear(28 * 28, 100),
                          nn.ReLU(),
                          QLinear(100, 10),
                          nn.Softmax())
  ```

Comment: thank you Ivan!! One more question is why will data attribute break the autograd. what if I want to initialize the weight using an trained weights. what should i do

Comment: If you assign values to a tensor through the data attribute, you won't be able to flow your gradients back during back propagation. This is relevant only during inference. So on your initialization, you can of course initialize your tensor/parameter however you prefer. Ideally, you can store your whole model's state dict and load it as is without any additional manipulation on your part.